# passing objects in jquery click event

Tags: jquery

I have this all wrong and its not working.

I'm trying to call one shared function to alert data passed that is called from two different click events  but |I get underfined in the alert. Why do I get underfined?

```
var myF = function(){
    alert('a click ' + this.model + ' ' + this.year); // meant to alert the properties of the object passed to it
    alert(this.ID); // meant to alert the ID of the click that called it
};

var myCar = new Object();
myCar.make = "Ford";
myCar.model = "Mustang";
myCar.year = 1969;

var myCar2 = mycar;
myCar2.make = "VW";
myCar2.model = "golf";
myCar2.year = 2000;


$('.feature1').click(myCar,myF);

$('.feature2').click(myCar2,myF);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the data in the event handler, you must use [`event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/):

```
var myF = function(e){
    alert('a click ' + e.data.model + ' ' + e.data.year); 
    alert(this.id);
};
```

Moreover, the property which contains the id is called `id`, not `ID`. And you have the typo `myCar2 = mycar` instead of `myCar2 = myCar`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rveaL/)

Answer (score 2):

In the callback, "this" refers to the element where you did the click. That function will receive your custom objects in the event parameter.

You could do it like this:

```
$('.feature1').click({myModel: myCar}, myF);
    var myF = function(e){
    var data = e.data.myModel;
    alert('a click ' + data.model + ' ' + data.year);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `undefined` because the `this` variable is the jquery anchor object. What would work in your case is

```
var myF = function(car){
alert('a click ' + car.model + ' ' + car.year); 
};

var myCar = new Object();
myCar.make = "Ford";
myCar.model = "Mustang";
myCar.year = 1969;

var myCar2 = new Object();
myCar2.make = "VW";
myCar2.model = "golf";
myCar2.year = 2000;


$('.feature1').click(function() { return myF(myCar); });    
$('.feature2').click(function() { return myF(myCar2); });
```

This is not the optimal way to do it, but it will get it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/MWxG8/

Comment: When you do this: myF(myCar) you are calling that function at that moment. That will not add the handler to the click function

Comment: this calls the function before the click

Comment: you'd need to return a function and not call the alert directly